# How to add a caption below a cell?

Tags: stylesheet, cells

How can I change my stylesheet definition for a cell to optionally add a  caption below?

For example, I would like to add a caption to my "Program" cells shown here:

[image]

like this (but with the option of right or left as well as centered alignment):

[image]

There are some caption-like things to be found in the docs:

[image]

But I would prefer to have the caption as part of the cell expression (not simply a separately styled cell put right below it)

I've tried CellFrameLabels, but I stumbled on a few things:

- Controlling alignments and styling
- Adding/removing them easily
- Auto-numbering

Related:

- [Extending cell definition to CellFrameLabels definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234720/extending-cell-definition-to-cellframelabels-definition)

Comment: Maybe try `CellFrameLabels`.

Comment: @Silvia Thanks, see my update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The purpose can be achieved with `CellFrameLabels`. Cell-expressions and Boxes can be used directly here, so styling can be done with `StyleBox`, alignment can be done with `PanelBox` etc. The counter mechanics is exact as [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421225/simon) demonstrated in [the linked Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7237782/935879) in OP.

Here is an example:

`cellFrameLabelFunc` uses `PanelBox` with `Alignment` to align label `lbl` from left (`-1`) to right (`1`):

```
Clear[cellFrameLabelFunc]
cellFrameLabelFunc[lbl_, align_: 0, color_: White] :=
    PanelBox[lbl,
        ImageSize -> {Scaled[1], Automatic},
        Alignment -> {align, Center},
        Appearance -> "Frameless", Background -> color
        ]
```

We pre-assign the `align_` then construct the label as following:

```
alignFraction = 0.3;

With[{
            counterSet = 
                ToString[Hue[#, .4, .95], StandardForm] & /@ Range[0, 1, .2]
            },

        testlbl =
            Style["my cell frame label", 13, Red, Italic, 
                            FontFamily -> "Constantia"] //
                        ToBoxes //
                    RowBox[{#, " & my counter : ",
                                CounterBox["myCounter", 
                                        CounterFunction :> (Part[counterSet, #] &)] //
                                    StyleBox[#,
                                            FontFamily -> "Constantia", FontSize -> 30,
                                            FontWeight -> Bold,
                                            FontColor -> Hue[0.75, 0.38, 0.78]] &
                                }] & //
                cellFrameLabelFunc[#, alignFraction] &
        ];
```

And generate the cells:

```
Cell["", CounterAssignments -> {{"myCounter", 0}}] // CellPrint

Cell[
        ConstantArray["this is the main body ", 6] // StringJoin,
        "myStyle",
        CellFrameLabels -> {{None, None}, {testlbl, None}},
        CounterIncrements -> "myCounter"
        ] // Do[CellPrint@#, {5}] &
```

[image: styled CellFrameLabels with auto-numbering]

Comment: Great answer as always!

Comment: @M.R. Thanks for acceptance!

Comment: What do you think is the easiest way to apply this to a single cell (that already exists in my notebook)?

Comment: @M.R. I would use `SetOptions[CellObject, CellFrameLabels->...]`.